# Spring JSP - How Can I Show a Request Value?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to echo back the cache operation selected in the Request, so that it is displayed on the browser.  I have very little JSP experience.  How can I get the value of ***operation*** to appear?

JSP:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Cache Operation Results - ${operation}</h1>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${results}" var="nextObject">
                <pre>${nextObject.toString()}</pre>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller snippet:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/objectcache", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView objectCache(@RequestParam("operation") String operation, HttpServletRequest req) {

    List<String> cacheReturnValue = new ArrayList<String>();
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/utils/objectCache", "results", cacheReturnValue);

    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
        cacheReturnValue = this.reloadCache();
    }

    mav.addObject("operation", operation);
    return new ModelAndView("/utils/objectCache", "results", cacheReturnValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The you have code *should* work properly **after removing a bug** - you've created `ModelAndView` twice and thus ignored "operation" added to first `ModelAndView` object. Solution - create `mav` only one time:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/objectcache", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView objectCache(@RequestParam("operation") String operation,
        HttpServletRequest req) {

    List<String> cacheReturnValue = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (operation.equalsIgnoreCase("reload")) {
        cacheReturnValue = this.reloadCache();
    }

    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/utils/objectCache");
    mav.addObject("results", cacheReturnValue);
    mav.addObject("operation", operation);
    return mav;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Small hint: since [`ModelAndView#addObject`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html#addObject%28java.lang.Object%29) returns reference to `this` object, you can chain it's calls without creating a variable `mav` like this:

```
return new ModelAndView("/utils/objectCache")
        .addObject("results", cacheReturnValue)
        .addObject("operation", operation);
```

Answer (score 0):

JSP pages have access to several [implicit objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp71043) via expressions. According to the examples given in that document, you can get your parameter value like so:

```
${param['operation']}
```